# GraphQL Mutation Returns Null From Neo4j Database using neo4j-graphql-js

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graphql

I have a mutation which is meant to create a Car and assign the car with an Owner. I am using Neo4j as the underlying database, so I extend the `cypher` directive in my Graphql schema file like so

```
    CreateCar(data: CarInput!): Car!
        @cypher(
            statement: """
            MERGE(s:Car {name: $data.name})
               ON CREATE
                SET s.id = apoc.create.uuid(), s.name = $data.name, s.description = $data.description, s.category = $data.category,
                 WITH s
                 MATCH(o:Owner {id: $cypherParams.currentUserId})
                 MERGE(o)-[:OWNS]->(s)
            RETURN s
            """
        )
```

When I run the above mutation in my Graphql playground, the mutation runs successfully as the data is inserted into the database, but I get a response from my playground that says `"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.CreateCar."` I also tried the same query using Neo4J Browser and it works, but running the mutation, data doesn't get returned back. Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: @xadm It's not auth, because a token is being passed into the request object and it's being decoded properly.

Comment: Use optional match for the :Owner